# Dependency of one class on three interfaces Guice

Tags: java, eclipse, dependency-injection, guice

I have the following application class which uses a server to run its logic
Implementation of the application class is as follows:

```
    package edu.umd.fcmd.guice.application;

import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.google.inject.Injector;


public class WebApplication {
    private WebServer server;

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("starting web application...");


        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new WebGuiceModule());
        server = injector.getInstance(WebServer.class);

        server.run();

        System.out.println("web application finished.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebApplication app = new WebApplication();

        app.run();
    }
}
```

The server class is as follows which depends on three interfaces:

```
public class WebServer{

    private final Frontend frontend;
    private final Middleware middleware;
    private final Persistance persistance;

    @Inject
    public WebServer(@Named("front")Frontend frontend, @Named("middle")Middleware middleware, @Named("pers")Persistance persistance) {

        this.frontend = frontend;
        this.middleware = middleware;
        this.persistance = persistance;
    }

    public String getType() {

        return "WebServer";
    }

    public boolean run() {

        System.out.println("running " + this.getType());

        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector();
        Frontend frontend = injector.getInstance(Frontend.class);
        frontend.run();
        Middleware middleware = injector.getInstance(Middleware.class);
        middleware.run();
        Persistance persistance = injector.getInstance(Persistance.class);
        persistance.run();

        return true;
    }
}
```

My webguicemodule is as follows:

```
public class WebGuiceModule extends AbstractModule{
    @Override
    protected void configure(){
        bind(WebServer.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("front")).to(FrontEnd.class);  
        bind(WebServer.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("middle")).to(Middleware.class);
        bind(WebServer.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("pers")).to(Persistance.class);
    }

}
```

I am not sure why my module is not working properly. It is still in errors when I am writing the bind statements. Could not figure out why
I am receiving the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The method to(Class<? extends WebServer>) in the type LinkedBindingBuilder<WebServer> is not applicable for the arguments (Class<FrontEnd>)
    FrontEnd cannot be resolved to a type
    The method to(Class<? extends WebServer>) in the type LinkedBindingBuilder<WebServer> is not applicable for the arguments (Class<Middleware>)
    Middleware cannot be resolved to a type
    The method to(Class<? extends WebServer>) in the type LinkedBindingBuilder<WebServer> is not applicable for the arguments (Class<Persistance>)
    Persistance cannot be resolved to a type
```

Comment: You have not stated what errors you're receiving.

Comment: @JeremyHeiler added them. if you could please view the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using `bind()` correctly. You've configured `WebGuiceModule` such that `FrontEnd`, `Middleware`, and `Persistance` are subclasses of `WebServer`. However, the compiler errors indicate that is not the case.

You just need to say:

```
bind(FrontEnd.class);
bind(Middleware.class);
bind(Persistance.class);
```

Then when you ask the injector for an instance of `WebServer`, it will know how to create the objects that it needs to pass into the constructor.

```
WebServer server = injector.getInstance(WebServer.class);
```

---

In this case, you don't need `@Named`. That is for a case like this:

```
public class Foo {

    @Inject
    public Foo(@Named("bar") Jar bar, @Named("tar") Jar tar) {
    }
}

public interface Jar {}
public class Bar extends Jar {}
public class Tar extends Jar {}
```

Then in a module...

```
bind(Jar.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("bar")).to(Bar.class);
bind(Jar.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("tar")).to(Tar.class);
```

The "name" disambiguates which implementation of `Jar` to create and inject. Otherwise it wouldn't know, and it would error.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @JeremyHeiler.
I am still having the following errors in the GuiceModule:
Multiple markers at this line
 - FrontEnd cannot be resolved to a type
 - The method bind(Class<FrontEnd>) from the type AbstractModule refers to the missing type 
  FrontEnd

Comment: Do you have a class called `FrontEnd`? If so, are you importing it correctly?

Comment: I figured out, it was not imported correctly. Do I have to create another GuiceModule if the 'FrontEnd' interface depends on another interface? @JeremyHeiler

Comment: You don't have to create another module. You just modify who you call `bind()`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @JeremyHeiler. This Frontend interface happens to be in a different package. Now, Frontend is dependent on an interface called authentication. When I tried implementing it with the similar code as that of the webserver, I am getting errors. The code I wrote was the following:

```
package edu.umd.fcmd.guice.interfaces;

import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import com.google.inject.Injector;

import edu.umd.fcmd.guice.application.WebServer;
import edu.umd.fcmd.guice.interfaces.Authentication;

public interface Frontend{
    private final Authentication authentication;

    @Inject
    public interface(Authentication authentication) {
        System.out.println("5");
        this.authentication = authentication;
    }
    public static String getType(){
        return "Frontend";
    }
    public default boolean run(){
        System.out.println("in frontend");
        authentication.run();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Errors are the following:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Duplicate field Frontend.authentication
    - Illegal modifier for the interface field Frontend.authentication; only public, static & final are 
     permitted

Syntax error on token "interface", Identifier expected

The static field Frontend.authentication should be accessed in a static way
```

I have tried searching a lot on the internet but could not find figure out. I guess the problem is having files in different packages. If you could please let me know.

Comment: This is not an "answer".  You should append (add at the bottom) to the original question...........with this information.............